# php returned array from preg_match_all

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

i have an array that is being returned like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ;3750;011; [1] => ;3750;012; [2] => ;3750;013; [3] =>  ;3750;014; [4] => ;3750;015; [5] => ;3750;016; [6] => ;3750;017; [7] => ;3750;018; [8] => ;3750;019; ))
```

the array is coming from preg_match_all

I have tried to print it with foreach loop and it always returns the same way
i can't work with it like this.. and i do not understand what is going on

this is the preg_match_all that it comes from:

```
$remove = preg_match_all('/;([\d]{4};[\d]{3});/', $str, $m);
```

Comment: try to use foreach with `$yourarray[0]`

Comment: i am talking seriously, i tried with $i=0; $youarray[$i]; $i++; in foreach and it always retuns like that!

Comment: when i print $m; or print($m); it does the same!

Comment: i mean print_r($m[$i]);

Comment: `foreach($yourarray[0] as $m) { echo $m.'<br>'; }`

Comment: i will try that, just a sec

Comment: tried already, the page just loads without running your script

Comment: can anybody help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_match_all()` returns in match result an array of arrays. Then to display all the whole matches you must use:

```
$remove = preg_match_all('/;([\d]{4};[\d]{3});/', $str, $m);

foreach($m[0] as $item) { echo $item . '<br/>'; }
```

If you only want the content of your capturing group, just replace `$m[0]` by `$m[1]`

Comment: ya, you were right, i had changed some of your initial code, that's why it wasn't working, thanks :)